# Don't understand this No module named 'tkinter' error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been using Jupyter notebook in AWS EMR when I run a program which requires graphical representations. I get this error:

```
 No module named 'tkinter'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line
    6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 5,
    in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Comment: OK, so have you installed the module?

Comment: I tried instaling module i can see no package tkinter available Error: nothing to do

Comment: What does `dnf search python3-tk` return? Can you confirm exactly which OS and which version you are using?

Comment: Its python 2.7 and OS is Redhat 4.6 of Amazon Linux

Comment: If it's 2.7, the package name is `Tkinter`, not `tkinter`. However, your error seems to show you're using 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run matplotlib with a non-interactive backend on a EC2 server as EC2 is headless. Configure your matplotlibrc file with this line.

```
backend : agg
```

To know more about this file, follow [this link](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install the python3-tk module. If you're using a debian-based distro then run `apt-get install python3-tk` from the command line.

Comment: I tried using sudo yum install python3-tk, sudo yum install tkinter and all. I can only see no module named these found

Comment: try yum install python3-tkinter and see if that works. @ManithKumar

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at this on a CentOS 7 VM (closest thing to your environment that I have set up right now). Because you are not using a software collection (definitely recommended), it looks like Tkinter can be installed with:

```
sudo yum install python33-python-tkinter.x86_64
```

But it looks like that is for Python 3.3 whereas you are using Python 3.4, so I'd suggest trying:

```
sudo yum install python34-python-tkinter.x86_64
```

---

## Finding Packages

If that does not work, the easiest way I know of to find the appropriate package is to do:

```
yum search tkinter | less
```

...and see what packages that turns up.

---

## Software Collection

If you go the route of software collections, you would need to install the appropriate Python distribution ([see the Software Collections site here](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python36/)), then install the appropriate tkinter version. For me, `yum search tkinter` brings up:

```
...
rh-python34-python-tkinter.x86_64
rh-python35-python-tkinter.x86_64
rh-python36-python-tkinter.x86_64
...
```

These are for the software collections and correspond to Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6.